# basic question about the dimension of induced modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional semi-simple $\Bbb{C}$-algebra, let $B \subset A$ be a (unital) subalgebra, and let $V$ be finite dimensional left $B$-module. Am I correct in thinking that the dimension $\text{dim}_\Bbb{C} \big(\acute{V} \big)$ of the induced module $\acute{V} = A \otimes_{B} V$ is **not** in general equal to

\begin{equation}
\text{dim}_\Bbb{C} \Bigg( {A \over B} \Bigg) \cdot \text{dim}_\Bbb{C} \, V \end{equation}

where the quotient $ \, \displaystyle {A \over B}$ means a quotient of vector spaces. best, ines.

Comment: What if $B=A{}$?

Comment: If $A = B$ then $\acute{V} \cong V$ as a left $A$-modules. So the formula is valid in that case, no ?

Comment: No, since $A/B$ has dimension zero as a vector space.

Comment: Thank you :) Do you know how this is computed in the general (in the semi-simple case) ? ines.

Comment: This is a delicate thing. You need a condtion like $A$ is free over $B$, so that $\mathrm{rank}_B(A)$ is well-defined. (For example, $\mathrm{rank}_A(A)=1$ with $\{1\}$ being an $A$-basis.)